# Excel file doesn't close using .Close method

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I've created a UDF that uses source excel file, exctact the data as the UDF result.

However, the source file doesn't close even if I use the .close method insine the 'with' - code below.

Any help with closing the source file after using it would be much appriciated, many thanks!

```
sfilename = "R:\values only.xlsb"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With GetObject(sfilename)
    range1 = .Sheets("RawData").Range("A:B")
    If IsError(Application.VLookup(lookupval, range1, 2, False)) Then
        If IsError(Application.VLookup(lookupval2, range1, 2, False)) Then
            MsgBox "Pair or date does not exist!"
        Else

            getex = 1 / Application.VLookup(lookupval2, range1, 2, False)

        End If

    Else

        getex = Application.VLookup(lookupval, range1, 2, False)

    End If
    .Close
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the only issue? What have you declared your variables as? I'd expect this line to throw an error too `range1 = .Sheets("RawData").Range("A:B")`. Also, have you got `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in your code without reverting it to default?

Comment: Is there error -handling in your UDF?

Comment: @EvR @Tom - The UDF works properly it just keeps the file open. No errors, and I don't have `On Error Resume Next` in my code. any ideas?

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: `Function getex(rdate As String, from1currency As String, tocurrency As String)`
@EvR That is what you meant for?

Comment: Nope,  do you call it in a sheet like =getex(....) or in Sub?

Comment: @EvR Yes, I call it in a sheet `=getex(a1,a2,a3)`

Comment: Don't use an/this UDF call in a formula on a sheet as most methods won't be executed, you could however open another instance of excel or place the outcome by a Sub in a cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment above, you could open your file in another instance (in same instance your UDF-formula call won't work)

```
 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     With objExcel
            .Visible = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
            With .Workbooks.Open(sfilename)
                range1 = .Sheets(2).Range("A:B")
                If IsError(Application.VLookup(lookupval, range1, 2, False)) Then
                    If IsError(Application.VLookup(lookupval2, range1, 2, False)) Then
                        MsgBox "Pair or date does not exist!" 'do not use msgbox but give getex a string => getex = "error"
                    Else
                        getex = 1 / Application.VLookup(lookupval2, range1, 2, False)
                    End If
                 Else
                        getex = Application.VLookup(lookupval, range1, 2, False)
                End If
            .Close
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
```

Another possibility is to place the outcome of your UDF by a Sub in the sheet (I would do that)

Comment: Thanks! The `.Quit` won't close **all** excel open workbooks?

Comment: Nope, only the new instance (objExcel)

Comment: Awesome! I think it worked! just to make sure, the `.Visible = False` and `.DisplayAlerts = False` relates only to the new instance (objExcel), right?

Comment: Yep, only to the new instance